# Find $(n,r)$ such that $C(n,r) =1984$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, problem-solving

I explored this problem a bit, trying various values of $r$

$r=0 \implies C(n,0) =1984$ which is impossible

$r=1 \implies C(n,1)=1984$ which yields our first solution (and probably the only one) $(n,r)=(1984,1)$

$r=2 \implies C(n,2)=1984 \iff n(n-1)=2\cdot 1984=3968$

Which is asking if there exists $2$ consecutive numbers that multiply out to $3968$

And this seems to continue for any $r>1$

So we can maybe reform the question into the language of number theory, if there exists $r$ consecutive numbers $n, n-1, ... , n-r+1$ such that $n(n-1)...(n-r+1)=r!\cdot1984$

There's a probably some other route that has to do with showing after a certain value of $r$, there are no other solutions too.

Comment: Kindly refer https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for making your question more presentable.

Comment: I meant "such that"

Comment: Since $1984=2^6\times 31$ we know that $n≥31$.  A quick search appears to rule out $r=2$ (should be easy to confirm).  And $r=3$ gives too large values from the start.

Comment: $\binom n2=1984$ gives $n^2-n-3968=0$ which has no rational roots, so it looks like $n=1984,r=1$ is the only possibility.

Comment: [A Combination Equation (n choose r = 1984)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg6jo10SzVk&list=RDCMUCW4czokv40JYR-w7u6aXZ3g)

Comment: Trivial, but of course if there's a solution for $r=1$ there's also a solution for $r=1983$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment

${32 \choose 2}=\frac{31\times 32}2$

${32 \choose 3}=5\times 31\times 32=2\times 64\times 31+2\times\frac{31\times 32}2$

$\Rightarrow 2\times 1984+2{32 \choose 2}={32 \choose 3}\rightarrow 1984=\frac12 [{32 \choose 3}+{32 \choose 2}]-\frac32{32 \choose 2}$

Using formula ${n+1 \choose r}={n \choose r}+{n \choose r-1}$, we obtain:

$1984=\frac12{33 \choose 3}-\frac32{32 \choose 2}$

So it seems that the is no integer solution except n=1984 and r=1.

Comment: Nice! I'll leave this question open for a couple more days for anyone who wants to formulate it into a full proof, (it will help me alot) otherwise I'll consider the question answered and close this thread.